# Why is my data not showing after I created a Pivot table?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

I'm building a web app and I'm using using Vue js for my front end. On the backend (Laravel), I've created a Pivot table between 2 tables employer_profiles and job_posts. A user can have One profile and a profile can have many job_posts.

I've created a table and I'm using a `v-for` loop to show the data. As you can see, I can access the `employerprofile` from within each `jobPosts`, but for some reason nothing is being displayed when I try to pull out the data like this `jobPost.employerprofile.property`.

Here is my table with the v-for loop:

```
<tr v-for="(jobPost, index) in jobPosts" :key="index">
    <td>
        <div class="job-company">{{jobPost.employerprofile.company_name}}</div>
    </td>
    <td><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> {{jobPost.employerprofile.country}}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="full-time">{{jobPost.employment_type}}</div>
    </td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> ${{jobPost.salary}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="apply-job-btn btn btn-radius theme-btn apply-it" data-post-id="457" data-user-id="1" title="Apply this job">
        <i class="flaticon-paper-plane"></i> Apply</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And here is a screenshot of the data when I `console.log()`. Any idea what's happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the screenshot, the `jobPost.employerprofile` property is an array, not an object.

And it looks like there's only 1 element in that array, so you can just get the first index:

```js
{{jobPost.employerprofile[0].company_name}}
```

### Advice:

If you don't know why some property is not being displayed, just try to display it outside the loop somehwere on the page, it's often easier to tell what's going on.

If you did something like the following you would find the problem:

```html
<!-- This would show you an array -->
{{jobPosts[0].employerprofile}}

<!-- This wouldn't return anything, so you would realise that
something is wrong with "employerprofile" -->
{{jobPosts[0].employerprofile.company_name}}
```

Comment: That's so funny, I tried ```jobPost[0].employerprofile[0]``` and ```jobPost[0].employerprofile``` but not ```jobPost.employerprofile[0]```. Thank you.